# Convex or non-convex function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I want to minimize the following function $$\frac{a}{bxy+cd}e^{\frac{a}{bxy+cd}}H+2-\Gamma(1,\frac{eaf}{b(1-x)},\frac{eagf}{bx(1-y)})$$ where $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,H$ are constants and greater than $0$. $\Gamma(a,x_1,x_2)$ is the generalized incomplete Gamma function. The minimization is to be performed with respect to $x,y$ with $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $0\leq y\leq 1$.

I tried to plot $\frac{a}{bxy+cd}e^{\frac{a}{bxy+cd}}H+1$ and $1-\Gamma(1,\frac{eaf}{b(1-x)},\frac{eagf}{bx(1-y)})$ for different values of $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,H$ and for those values it appears that both are convex. Since, the sum of two convex functions is also convex therefore I can conclude that the function is convex for those special values of $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,H$. However, I do not know how to show that the above function is convex or otherwise for general values of $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,H$.

I believe that the highest product of $x$ and $y$ minimizes $\frac{a}{bxy+cd}e^{\frac{a}{bxy+cd}}H+1$ (because as $xy\to\infty$ the value approach 1). Can this information simplify this problem?
I will be very thankful for any help in this regard.

Comment: What do you mean by $\Gamma(1, \ldots, \ldots)$?  I am only aware of Gamma functions of one or two variables, not three.

Comment: @RobertIsrael It represent the generalized incomplete gamma function http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma3/. I have added this in my post also

Comment: According to that page $\Gamma(1,u,v) = \int_u^v \exp(-t)\; dt = \exp(-u) - \exp(-v)$.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @RobertIsrael here is another reference that shows the definition of genralized incomplete gamma function. Eq. 5 of the paper in http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0377042794901872 . I do not know why the definition is not similar in wolfram and in this paper. However, I am using the definition from this paper. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The first summand $$f(x,y) = \dfrac{a}{bxy + cd} e^{\frac{a}{bxy+cd}} H$$
is  not convex.  Its Hessian at $(0,0)$ is 
$$ \left[ \begin {array}{cc} 0&-{\frac {Hab \left( a+{\it cd} \right) }{
{{\it cd}}^{3}}{{\rm e}^{{\frac {a}{{\it cd}}}}}}\\
-{\frac {Hab \left( a+{\it cd} \right) }{{{\it cd}}^{3}}{{\rm e}^{{
\frac {a}{{\it cd}}}}}}&0\end {array} \right] 
$$
which is not positive semidefinite (it has both positive and negative eigenvalues).  Thus for sufficiently small positive $x, y$ there will still be a negative eigenvalue.